# Django form initial pass a list to one attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I met an issue when I want to pass a list of value to one attribute during initial the form.

The whole process of what I am doing is: 
1. User defines a number N.
2. I display N text field.
3. User fills in data and I store in the database.
4. User wants to modify the data -> which is the issue I have when. I want to initial the form with current data.

Here is my model.py

```
class PageComponent(models.Model):
    componentName=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, verbose_name="Name")
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AS_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    page = models.ForeignKey(CommunityPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    STATUS = (
        ('a', 'Activated'),
        ('d', 'Deactivated'),
    )

    componentStatus=models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=STATUS,
        blank=False,
        default='d',
        help_text='the current status of the page component', editable=False
    )

    textContent=models.TextField(max_length=10000, help_text="Enter a description for your component", null=True, blank=True)
    photoContent=models.ImageField(upload_to=component_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Photo")
    videoContent=models.FileField(upload_to=component_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Video")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.componentName

class PageComponent_SeasonalText(models.Model):
    pageStextComponent = models.ForeignKey(PageComponent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seasonalText = models.CharField(max_length=10001)
```

Here is my form.py

```
class SeasonalTextForm(forms.Form):
    componentName = forms.CharField(label=_('Enter title'),max_length=40)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        seasonTexts = kwargs.pop('extra')
        super(SeasonalTextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # self.cleaned_data = {}
        for i in range(0, seasonTexts):
            field_name = 'seasonText_%s' % (i,)
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':10, 'cols':51}))

        #set field label as placeholder for every field
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs["placeholder"] = field.label

    def clean(self):
        seasonTexts = set()
        i = 0
        field_name = 'seasonText_%s' % (i,)
        while self.cleaned_data.get(field_name):
            seasonText = self.cleaned_data[field_name]
            if seasonText in seasonTexts:
                self.add_error(field_name, 'Duplicate')
            else:
                seasonTexts.add(seasonText)
            i += 1
            field_name='seasonText_%s' % (i,)
        self.cleaned_data["seasonTexts"] = seasonTexts

    def save(self):

        for seasonalText in self.cleaned_data["seasonTexts"]:
            PageComponent_SeasonalText.objects.create(pageStextComponent = PageComponent.pageStextComponent,seasonalText = seasonalText,)
```

Here is my view.py

```
def edit_stext(request, page_id, id):
    page = get_object_or_404(CommunityPage, pk=page_id)
    component = PageComponent.objects.get(id=id)
    stext = PageComponent_SeasonalText.objects.filter(pageStextComponent=component)
    numOfSeasons = page.numSeasons
    if request.method == "POST":
        stextEditor = SeasonalTextForm(request.POST, instance=stext, extra=numOfSeasons)
        if stextEditor.is_valid():
            stextEditor.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('page', kwargs={'page_id' : page_id}))
    else:
        # stext1 = PageComponent_SeasonalText.objects.filter(pageStextComponent=component)
        initial = {}
        initial['componentName'] = component.componentName
        for i in range(0,numOfSeasons):
            st = stext[i].seasonalText
            print(st)
            initial['seasonalText_{}'.format(i)] = st
        stextEditor = SeasonalTextForm(initial=initial, extra=numOfSeasons)
    return render(request, 'editComponent_stext.html', {'stextEditor': stextEditor})
```

NB:
at the view.py, I have a print function to print the actual value of the attribute "seasonalText" and it is success. But it seems cannot be passed to the initial when I want to initial the form.

Thanks for all spending time to help me with this issue. Many thanks.

Screenshot for understanding:

[print function gets the correct value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82wBf.jpg)

[initialed form doesn't get the seasonalText value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy6sO.jpg)

Comment: can you add a little more explanation in short?

Comment: @NimishBansal hi bansal, in brief, the issue that I have is in the view.py. " stextEditor = SeasonalTextForm(initial=initial, extra=numOfSeasons)", the value in initial cannot pass to the form

Comment: and how can you say that value is not passing to the form?

Comment: @nimishBansal The print function can print the value at the console, but I look at the form, the value doesn't appear on the form. I uploaded the screenshot, the first one is the value printed at the console and the second one is my form.